# How to create a Bootstrap grid inside a element that sizes based on content?

Tags: bootstrap-4, grid

I have a requiremnt to put a grid inside a modal and modal need to sizes based on the content.

Following jsfiddle shows the basic requirement

```
<div class="pro-modal-outer">
<div class="pro-modal">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="field">short</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="field long">
        extra extra long content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="field">long content</div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nash171/5c1t7dkv/17/

As you see here, some contents of a column overflow to next column.

[image]

Columns width need to be size based on it's content and container width need to adjust according to it.

In real case, content will be dynamic. Any column can contain different size child elements as content

All columns need to get equal width as well

Is there any possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

For "extra extra long content" use class="col-sm-6" and for long content use class="col-sm-4" and for short use class="col-sm-2" so that the columns width size adjust accordingly. If you using custom classes try to give width in "%" instead of px.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in this case content is dynamic. Any column can get different size child elements as content. (Sorry I didn't mention it in the question. now updated). And all columns should get equal width as well. that's why i am using col-4

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the width by giving values in % instead of px and try it...

Answer (score 0):

remove this content from your css code.

```
.field {
    width: 100px;
}
.field.long {
    width: 250px;
}
```

your code works fine as you want.

the following snippet shows the result what you want.

```css
.pro-modal-outer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.pro-modal {
  background-color: #68acff;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 660px;
}
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.col-4, .col-6 {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="pro-modal-outer">
    <div class="pro-modal">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">1 of 2</div>
          <div class="col-6">2 of 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <div class="field">short</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <div class="field long">extra extra long content</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <div class="field">long content</div>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this will works fine for you.

Thank You...

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. But content of a column is dynamic, so not sure which column get the longest content. and all columns should have a equal width as well.

Comment: @NadeeshPeiris I have just update my answer please review it, I hope this will help to solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it not possible to remove sizing of child elements. I used that element with specified width and text as content to demonstrate the issue. It can be any element as content.

Comment: if you want fix width and 3 equal parts then both not possible you have to compromise for any one of this. if you want fix width of content the first solution is perfect and if you want 3 equal parts then this edited solution is perfect.

Comment: one other solution is that if you increase the box width but in responsive it looks different. not display the same view

Comment: edit my answer again, in this solution you have to remove the fix width of content.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Yes It seems its not possible have a perfect solution for this.
As in your solution, a width need to set to container (pro-modal). But in my case, it doesn't have a width. It should adjust according to the grid content.